# Remove focus on Boostrap 5 toggle button after click

Tags: javascript, html, user-experience, togglebutton, bootstrap-5

I am trying to work with the Bootstrap 5 Toggle Button (using the Outline Style for a more evident visual emphasis). However, the UX experience is not quite what I'm hoping for.
(See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#outlined-styles)

The toggle per se works well, its the focus (or after the click focus I should say) that's the problem. When the button is in an unchecked state, the visual clue is prominent since the button is outlined. When the button is in an checked state, again the visual clue is prominent because the button is filled. When the button transitions from an unchecked to checked state, the change is evident as it transitions from outlined to filled.

The problem is when unchecking. When the button transitions from a checked to unchecked state, the button remains filled until a) the mouse is moved on device with a cursor, or b) another location on the page is touched on a touch device. The user obviously believes that they have not unchecked the button when it has in fact been unchecked and then proceeds to continue to attempt to uncheck the button.

The problem is even more evident when dealing with multiple checkboxes in a button group.
(See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/button-group/#checkbox-and-radio-button-groups)

I have tried using javascript to call `blur` on the checkbox's `click` event, and although that approach has a limited degree of success, it does nothing on touch devices as the virtual pointer for the device remains hovering over the button. I also tried calling `focus` on a different element on the page with the same result.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm seeing this too .. may well be an actual bug - can you please add it to the project here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues

Comment: The "bug" is in `mixins/_buttons.scss` in the `@mixin button-outline-variant` ... it defines both `.btn-check:checked + &` and `.btn-check:active + &` with the same styling.

Answer (score 2):

Was submitted for bugfix here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34664

Comment: Still no official fix in 5.2 as far as I can tell via the repo issue threads.